# Suppressing functionality of the super class, is it good design?

Tags: java, gwt, interface

I was reading the book "GWT in action 2", and the author mentioned (in the section where the developer can create a custom widget by extending another one) a hint on how to stop/suppress some functionality of the super class, i.e. methods given by the implemented interfaces.

The way that the author provided was to override the method and add an exception to the GWT log for the developer. Example:

```
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler){ 
    GWT.log("", new Exception("Cannot add ClickHandler to ReportSizeLabel"));                      
    return null;                                                  
}
```

Why would I do that, is this a good design?

Why not just return a null, if you must do such a ting?

Maybe I'm thinking too much, anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is basically bad.  Returning null is not helpful for the programmer (it would be better to throw an exception), and the whole thing breaks the idea of polymorphism.

So, the RIGHT answer would be to make an alternative chain of interfaces, to get all of the functions you need but not include `HasClickHandlers`.  However, practically, that can take a lot of time.  If this function threw an exception instead of returning null I'd be willing to put it in internally-used code, but I wouldn't publish this code to be used by others.

PS: the RIGHT answer is probably to correctly implement the method - it's not that hard in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything inherently wrong with this. If a function from the parent doesn't make logical sense for the child, then disabling it seems like a rational thing to do. Logging an error lets you know it happenned.

Whether returning null as a method of disabling is a good idea depends on what the function does. If the caller is checking for the null return and then calling a panic-abort function, it would make more sense to throw an exception. But if the function "normally", say, returns some object that gets stuffed in a collection, then returning a null and letting the caller put a null in the collection might be a reasonable thing to do.

Sure, if you find yourself disabling many functions from a parent class or interface, at some point you have to ask whether you're really implementing this interface or just implementing some other interface that happens to resemble this one. But if the interface declares 100 functions and you disable 2 of them, I think defining a new interface for the subset is a bad idea: It means that there are now two definitions of each of those 98 functions that will have to be maintained. If it wasn't an interface but a parent class, this would be even worse. It means there would now be two copies of 98 functions. Duplicate code is a much worse thing than a handfall of disabled functions.